# What is wrong with my goldfish's head?

Tags: diseases, goldfish

What is wrong with my goldfish's head - it's like a growth/ blood blister? I'm sure it started off white and has now gone to this. Can anyone help, please?

[image]

Comment: Wow, I’ve never seen that on my goldfish!

Comment: Theres a similar question here: https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/31078/my-goldfish-started-growing-a-flower-like-thing-on-his-head-and-it-is-now-distur

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My goldfish started growing a flower-like thing on his head and it is now disturbing it during eating](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/31078/my-goldfish-started-growing-a-flower-like-thing-on-his-head-and-it-is-now-distur)