# My goldfish started growing a flower-like thing on his head and it is now disturbing it during eating

Tags: health, fish, eating, skin-condition, goldfish

My pet goldfish, Mentos, has a **flower-like structure growing on his head**. At first, we didn't take it as a big issue. Now, it started concerning us and the fish itself because it **blocks him from eating his food properly**. He still does manage to eat a bit though. The flower-like structure would get inside his mouth and he'd try to spit it out meanwhile trying to eat his food as well. Therefore, to eat, at times, he'd tilt his head and eat; but again, not always and it's really troubling for him. **What should I do?**

I think it has been there for almost five-six months. We didn't try anything in the fear of causing more problems without knowing much. The fish, despite having such a thing on his head and his inability to eat comfortably, is absolutely healthy and hasn't been seen to show off discomfort in any manner.

I searched up in Google, but I couldn't find anything similar. The structure grown is quite fluffy and is connected to a small or a thin structure which is connected to his head.

I hope there is a solution so that he can eat easily like others without any inconvenience. :)

(He just right now had it in his mouth and spat it out and it dangles over his head. It happens constantly and it's really concerning.)

[image: My goldfish, Mentos.## Heading ##]

[image]

Comment: Does it looks like "Lymphocystis"? I searched for "goldfish skin growing" and it seems to look similar...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

THIS IS A MEDICAL EMERGENCY!

Your fish may be infected with the viral infection called lymphocystis. There is really no direct cure for it, but your veterinarian can suppress the virus until it eventually stops. Many prayers to your fish. This is a decision you will have to make yourself.

As well with that, it will not go away on its own. I would not recommend taking it off on your own because it may cause pain to the fish and make it worse.